# Adjusting font size to its container size (widths and heights noted)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I want to resize the font of a button dynamically, so that when inserting a text in the button, it automatically adjusts so the complete text is displayed. The size of the text can vary. It can be 5 or 30 words. Does anyone encountered this before and know how to solve this?

Comment: Some Fiddle Example for testing: https://jsfiddle.net/sebsti/8L6c8wre/8/

Comment: you want to resize font size of button or you want to resize the button itself?

Comment: i want to resize the font size of the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with a loop now and it works well. If you got a more performant solution i'd like to hear it.

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/sebsti/8L6c8wre/11/)

```
function sizeButtonTextLabel(id){

$("label[for='" + id + "'] div").css('font-size', "1ems"); 

while( $("label[for='" + id + "'] div").height() > $("label[for='" + id + "']").height() ) {
        $("label[for='" + id + "'] div").css('font-size', parseInt($("label[for='" + id + "'] div").css('font-size'))- 0.5 +"px");
    }
}

//initial sizing
sizeButtonTextLabel('checkbox-h-1a');
sizeButtonTextLabel('checkbox-h-1b');
sizeButtonTextLabel('checkbox-h-2a');
sizeButtonTextLabel('checkbox-h-2b');

//sizing when changing window height/width
$(window).resize(function() {   
sizeButtonTextLabel('checkbox-h-1a');
sizeButtonTextLabel('checkbox-h-1b');
sizeButtonTextLabel('checkbox-h-2a');
sizeButtonTextLabel('checkbox-h-2b');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the jQuery plugin [BigText](https://github.com/zachleat/BigText) that will match font size to a certain width.

Unfortunately, there is no pure CSS solution. Your best option would be to use the "viewport width" unit for font-sizing:

```
    font-size: 5vw;
```

This sizes fonts relative to the width of the viewport.

Comment: Tried BigText now, but it seems not to be able to perform a wordwrap so the text is not be displayed completely at my button. How would i solve this or did i just overlooked it?

https://jsfiddle.net/sebsti/8L6c8wre/9/